# Can not for each in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I tried to use for each loop to iterate through HashMap keys but it doesn't compile.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class theseeker{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Map blue = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        for(char c = 'a';c <= 'z';c++)
            blue.put(new Character(c),new Integer((int)c));

        for(Character c : blue.keySet())
            System.out.println(c);


    }


}
```

I get this error:

```
 Object cannot be converted to Character
        for(Character c : blue.keySet())
                                     ^
```

Does it happen beacuse of using interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're map defaults to objects set it's casts

```
Map<Character, Integer> blue = new HashMap<>();
```

After cleaning up your code it should look like the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> blue = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        blue.put(c, (int) c);
    }

    for (Character c : blue.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it workes. So when I use interface Map I have to specify the Base_type of key and value. Am ı right?

Comment: No you don't it is already specified `<Character, Integer>`

Comment: Okay I got it now. Default type of Interface Map is <Object, Object>, when I try to iterate by using for each loop type Object can not be cast to Character so I had to Define interface with appropriate type.

Thank you